# SharePoint calculation query

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a column in my list that states a date, we can refer to that column as X.  I need some help, I want to make a column that would show the quarters based on column X For eg

January-March is Quarter 1
April - June is Quarter 2
July - September  is Quarter 3
October - December is Quarter 4

So whenever X shows a certain date based on that this new column will show the appropriate Quarter.

Hope someone can help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This Formula is better to read:

```
="Quarter " & CHOOSE( MONTH([ColumnX])  ,1,1,1 ,2,2,2 ,3,3,3 ,4,4,4 )
```

More: [www.viewmaster365.com/functions](http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions)

Comment: Note that this will return "Quarter 4" if `ColumnX` is empty.

Comment: Well spotted. Because Dates start counting at 1/1/1900 an **empty** Date is December 1899, thus Month( ) returns 12

Answer (score 1):

Create a **Calculated Column** and enter the following formula for it on Column X

```
=IF(MONTH(ColumnX)<=3,"Q1", IF(MONTH(ColumnX)<=6,"Q2", IF(MONTH(ColumnX)<=9,"Q3",IF(MONTH(ColumnX)<=12,"Q4",""))))
```

where **ColumnX** is a column of type Date and Time.

Comment: Hi. I already have a column X that shows the date, so I wanted to create another column that would show the quarters according to the date, column X presents. Can you please help

Comment: For example: X= 01/01/2016 so the column i want to create should show Quarter 1 in that column

Comment: I am not sure, I am understanding you correctly but the above formula is for the other column. Create a new column and choose the column type as "Calculated". Then, under the options below, enter the formula as above and Save.